# Exception handling in Dataframe operations

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

We have a pyspark program that reads data from csv file into a dataframe and performs a series of processing.

We first use string datatype in the schema and then after few initial data cleanup, we enforce the known input schema.

We have noticed that for certain mismatches between actual datatype of data and the schema enforced, the column value is set to NULL.

Example,

```
Datatype of column in the csv file: Decimal(23,0)
Datatype applied through schema: Decimal(19,0)

# we first read the file using default string schema
pf1=spark.read.csv(input_file_path,string_schema)

....perform some cleanup....
....We observe no issues with the data till this stage....

col_names = pf1.schema.names
for column_name in col_names:
    pf1=pf1.withColumn(column_name, pf1[column_name].cast(functions.struct_type(<we get the actual datatype for the column dynamically>)))

Result: For records with digits greater than 19, value is changed to NULL
```

Is there any way we can catch such exceptions or truncations while doing dataframe withColumn operation ?

Adding an example with value:

```
dft=spark.createDataFrame(["40722000113079650001"],StringType()).toDF("number")
dft.show(1,False)
+--------------------+
|number              |
+--------------------+
|40722000113079650001|
+--------------------+

dfnew=dft.withColumn("number",dft["number"].cast(DecimalType(19,0)))
dfnew.show(1,False)
+------+
|number|
+------+
|null  |
+------+
```

While we take care to ensure datatype enforced is as accurate as possible, is there any way where error can be thrown when value is defaulted to NULL upon truncation ?

Comment: Could you please provide some sample csv data?

Comment: Hi, I've added an example with value. It is the same value in csv file in the column of question.